# Are my dried moong dal beans bad?

Tags: indian-cuisine, beans, lentils

I have some moong dal that I bought at an Indian market a few months ago. I've stored them in a sealed tupperware container. When I opened them today (to make them for dinner tonight), they smell strongly - not necessarily bad, but pungent. Is this normal? Or have they gone bad?

Comment: I prefer to keep Moong Dal in BPA free containers or Jars. They stay dry. It's strange that there is a strong smell in them. I have never encountered smelly moong in all these years. Maybe like @banavalikar said, it must be the tupperware causing it. When you wash them in water check if there are tiny insects are not floating around. If they are then you found the culprit.

Comment: Check expiry date if you still have the packet. I usually cut off the date and place it in the container for future use.I don't trust some Indian stores with long life products. They often forget to remove expired products from shelf. I almost bought kgs of spices from a store which had expired a month ago.

Answer (score 2):

Moong dal has a characteristic odour that concentrates over the time in a closed container (like Tupperware). So you are good. Just make sure that the dal is not stuck in clusters, has changed colour or has developed mold. In which case you will have to discard it.

Answer (score 2):

It does sound strange to me. I always get my lentils and pulses for months and store but never they smelled pungent.
It will have its own characteristic aroma. 
If it is rather pungent there should be some reason as to why. Please analyze it.
Wash it and check if the smell goes off. If not, I would be hesitant to use it.